# I got problem while using Nginx to direct requests to services defined in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm setting up an app with multiple containers, and use nginx to redirect requests to correct container. However, I got stuck with the 502 Bad Gateway error.

Actually, the code is from a course on Udemy: Docker and Kubernetes.
I just copy and paste the code, it ran on instructor machine, but not mine. I tried on my windows and my macbook, restart docker, but still no hope. I looked for solutions on other stackoverflow posts, some other articles, but none of them tell me why it works on others' machines, but not mine.

Here is the [repo of the code](https://github.com/PercyPham/docker-fib/tree/c3da30f0f171bcd4a61695657cc389955b82f74f).

docker-compose.yml ([full code](https://github.com/PercyPham/docker-fib/blob/c3da30f0f171bcd4a61695657cc389955b82f74f/docker-compose.yml)):

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    ...
  redis:
    ...
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
  api:
    ...
  client:
    ...
  worker:
    ...
```

nginx/Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx/default.conf

```
upstream client {
  server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
  server api:5000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://client;
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://api;
  }
}
```

It runs just fine on instructor's machine and other learners', but not on my machines. I got error when connecting `http://localhost:3050` and `http://localhost:3050/api`:

```
nginx_1     | 2019/07/08 02:52:35 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://125.235.4.59:3000/", host: "localhost:3050"
nginx_1     | 172.25.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2019:02:52:35 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1     | 2019/07/08 02:52:57 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://125.235.4.59:3000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost:3050", referrer: "http://localhost:3050/"
nginx_1     | 172.25.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2019:02:52:57 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost:3050/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The proxy config looks correct however it doesn’t look like you’re exposing the client / api ports. Can test adding the ports to “expose” in you docker-compose.yml?

Comment: You mean the EXPOSE flag in Dockerfile in client and api folder?

Comment: I tried, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Can add a “depends_on: ...” client / api to your nginx service to make sure those services are up before nginx starts (with the dependent services’ ports exposed)?

Comment: Yes, it works now, thank you very much @masseyb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Needed to amend the `docker-compose.yml`:

1. the upstream services should expose their ports so that the `nginx` service can connect i.e.:

```
  api:
    expose:
    - '5000'

  client:
    expose:
    - '3000'
```

2. the `nginx` service `depends_on` the upstream services:

```
  nginx:
    depends_on:
    - 'client'
    - 'api'
```

Comment: Actually, I checked, only the `depends_on` will do the trick, the 'expose' part is just like a comment to communicate between developers, nginx doesn't read that property. However, some other services might read that, for example, AWS Elastic Beanstalk will read it to do auto mapping.